# Animated borderbrush color in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make animated borderbrush in WPF application. I would like the 2 colors to "move" all over borderbrush using LinearGradientBrush

```
<Border
    CornerRadius="15"
    BorderThickness="3">

    <Border.Background>
    #222222
    </Border.Background>

    <Border.BorderBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" Opacity="0.9">
    <GradientStop Color="#f51111" Offset="0.3" />
    <GradientStop Color="#f59211" Offset="0.7" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.BorderBrush>

    </Border>
```

Comment: Do you have sample code for what you've tried, or surrounding context, please?

Comment: If possible, please edit above comment into the question for readability.  I myself cannot answer, but  perhaps someone else will.

Comment: @JosephDoggie Post has been edited

Comment: I am trying to animate color wave in <Border.BorderBrush/>

Comment: You've still not explained properly. You can animate angle on a rotatetransform. <LinearGradientBrush.Transform> <RotateTransform

Comment: Or you could animate those offsets.

Comment: @Andy Yes, i want to animate GradientStop offsets

Comment: Did you not try a web search? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-the-position-or-color-of-a-gradient-stop?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @Andy yes i did that